# Problem with null reference passing data to a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm passing data from a firebase database to a RecyclerView in an Activity through a RecyclerView Adapter.

I can't see any error, but everytime i try to access to this activity the app crashes.

This Activity has also some spinners to make filters to select only some objects from the database; but even i removed this part of the code, it isn't still working.

The RecyclerView Activity:

```java
public class Lista extends AppCompatActivity {

    //ListView listatocha;
    DatabaseReference bbdd;
    Button btnreestablecer;

    RecyclerView rcvg;
    Adaptagrande rAdapterg;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManagerg;
    List<Juego> juegostocha;

    Spinner spncons;
    Spinner spnform;
    Spinner spnpos;
    Spinner spnavan;
    Spinner spnvec;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista);
       // listatocha = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstvwlistgrand);
        btnreestablecer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btntitlsrc);
        rcvg = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclergrande);
        rcvg.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext())); //a ver si
        juegostocha = new ArrayList<>();
        rAdapterg = new Adaptagrande(getApplicationContext(),juegostocha);
        rcvg.setAdapter(rAdapterg);

        bbdd = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("juegos");

        spncons = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnplataformal);
        spnform = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnformatol);
        spnpos = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnposesionl);
        spnavan = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnavancel);
        spnvec = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnvecesl);


        /*
        spncons.setSelection(0);
        spnform.setSelection(0);
        spnpos.setSelection(0);
        spnavan.setSelection(0);
        spnvec.setSelection(0);
        */

        String[] plataformas = new String[] {"Plataforma","PC", "PS2", "PS3", "PS4", "N64", "Gamecube", "Wii", "WiiU", "NSwitch", "Xbox", "Xbox360", "XboxOne", "PSone", "GameBoy", "GBA", "DS", "3DS", "PSP", "PSVita"}; //2-8 | 2.2 3.8 4.2 5.1 6.1 7.4 8.1
        String[] avance = new String[] {"Avance","Nulo", "Probado", "Intermedio", "Pasado", "Completado", "Irrelevante"}; //4-11 | 4.1 6.1 7.1 10.2 11.1
        String[] veces = new String[] {"Veces","0","1","2","3-5","+5"}; //0-3
        String[] posesion = new String[] {"Posesión","Si","No"};  //siempre igual
        String[] formato = new String[] {"Físico","Si","No"};     //siempre igual

        ArrayAdapter<String> adaptaforms = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, plataformas);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adaptavanc = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, avance);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adaptveces = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, veces);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adaptapose = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, posesion);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adaptaform = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, formato);

        spncons.setAdapter(adaptaforms);
        spnvec.setAdapter(adaptveces);
        spnavan.setAdapter(adaptavanc);
        spnpos.setAdapter(adaptapose);
        spnform.setAdapter(adaptaform);



        spncons.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               cosa();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        spnpos.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                cosa();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        spnform.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                cosa();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        spnavan.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                cosa();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
        spnvec.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                cosa();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        btnreestablecer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                spncons.setSelection(0);
                spnform.setSelection(0);
                spnpos.setSelection(0);
                spnavan.setSelection(0);
                spnvec.setSelection(0);
            }
        });
    }


    protected void cosa(){
        bbdd.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                juegostocha.clear();
                //ArrayAdapter<String> adaptadorr;
                //ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
                String busqueda = "Buscando ";

                for (DataSnapshot datasnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    dataSnapshot.getValue(Juego.class);
                    Juego juego = datasnapshot.getValue(Juego.class);

                    String titulo = juego.getTitulo();
                    String plataforma = juego.getPlataforma();
                    String poses = juego.getPosesion();
                    String forma = juego.getFisico();
                    String avanc = juego.getAvance();
                    String veces = juego.getVeces();
                    //String juegolst = titulo;

                    //esto antes iba por listview



                    //juegolst = juegolst+" |  "+"  |  "+plataforma+"  |  "+poses+"  |  "+forma+"  |  "+avanc+"  |  "+veces;


                    if (spncons.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Plataforma")&&spnform.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Físico")&&spnpos.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Posesión")&&spnavan.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Avance")&&spnvec.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Veces")){
                        //lista.add(juegolst);
                        juegostocha.add(juego);
                        busqueda = "Buscando todos los ";
                    }else{
                        if (plataforma.equals(spncons.getSelectedItem().toString())|| spncons.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Plataforma")){
                            if (poses.equals(spnpos.getSelectedItem().toString())|| spnpos.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Posesión")){
                                if (forma.equals(spnform.getSelectedItem().toString())|| spnform.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Físico")){
                                    if (avanc.equals(spnavan.getSelectedItem().toString())|| spnavan.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Avance")){
                                        int numveces = Integer.parseInt(veces);

                                        if (spnvec.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Veces")){
                                            //lista.add(juegolst);
                                            juegostocha.add(juego);
                                        }else{
                                            switch (numveces) {
                                                case 0:
                                                    if (spnvec.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("0")){
                                                        //lista.add(juegolst);
                                                        juegostocha.add(juego);
                                                    }
                                                    break;
                                                case 1:
                                                    if (spnvec.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("1")){
                                                        //lista.add(juegolst);
                                                        juegostocha.add(juego);
                                                    }
                                                    break;
                                                case 2:
                                                    if (spnvec.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("2")){
                                                        //lista.add(juegolst);
                                                        juegostocha.add(juego);
                                                    }
                                                    break;
                                                case 3:
                                                    if (spnvec.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("3-5")){
                                                        //lista.add(juegolst);
                                                        juegostocha.add(juego);
                                                    }
                                                    break;
                                                case 4:
                                                    if (spnvec.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("3-5")){
                                                        //lista.add(juegolst);
                                                        juegostocha.add(juego);
                                                    }
                                                    break;
                                                case 5:
                                                    if (spnvec.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("3-5")){
                                                        //lista.add(juegolst);
                                                        juegostocha.add(juego);
                                                    }
                                                    break;
                                                    default:
                                                        if (spnvec.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("+5")){
                                                            //lista.add(juegolst);
                                                            juegostocha.add(juego);
                                                    }
                                                        break;

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }



                }

                rAdapterg.notifyDataSetChanged();

                //adaptadorr = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Lista.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lista);
              //  listatocha.setAdapter(adaptadorr);

                if (spncons.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Plataforma")){
                    busqueda = busqueda + "juegos para cualquier plataforma, ";
                }else{
                    busqueda = busqueda + "juegos para "+spncons.getSelectedItem().toString()+", ";
                }
                if (spnpos.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Si")){
                    busqueda = busqueda + "en posesión, ";
                }else{
                    if (spnpos.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("No")){
                        busqueda = busqueda + "NO en posesión, ";
                    }
                }

                if (spnform.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Si")){
                    busqueda = busqueda + "en físico, ";
                }else{
                    if (spnform.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("No")){
                        busqueda = busqueda + "en digital, ";
                    }else{
                        busqueda = busqueda + "en cualquier formato, ";
                    }
                }
                busqueda = busqueda +"con un grado de avance ";
                if (spnavan.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Avance")){
                    busqueda = busqueda+"cualquiera y pasado ";
                }else{
                    busqueda = busqueda+spnavan.getSelectedItem().toString()+" y pasado ";
                }
                if (spnvec.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Veces")){
                    busqueda = busqueda+"cuantas veces sea";
                }else{
                    busqueda = busqueda+spnvec.getSelectedItem().toString()+" veces.";
                }

                //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),busqueda,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                //toast.show();

                //Ahora es un snackbar lo que se crea con la info. de la búsqueda, y se queda hasta que la cierres

                final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), busqueda, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);

                snackBar.setAction("Entendido", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        snackBar.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                snackBar.show();

            } //aqui acaba el on data change

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

The Adapter java file:

```java
public class Adaptagrande extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adaptagrande.jHolder>{

    List<Juego> jueguiss;
    private Context micontext;

    public Adaptagrande(Context micontext, List<Juego> jueguiss){
        this.jueguiss = jueguiss;
        this.micontext = micontext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public jHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup grupo, int i){
        View vv = LayoutInflater.from(grupo.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_juegofull, grupo, false);
        jHolder holdeer = new jHolder(vv);

        return holdeer;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final jHolder holder, final int pos){
        final Juego j1 = jueguiss.get(pos);
        holder.titxtlist.setText(j1.getTitulo());
        holder.platxtlist.setText(j1.getPlataforma());
        holder.posetxtlist.setText(j1.getPosesion());
        holder.formatxtlist.setText(j1.getFisico());
        holder.avatxtlist.setText(j1.getAvance());
        holder.vectxtlist.setText(j1.getVeces());
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return jueguiss.size();
    }

    public static class jHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView titxtlist;
        public TextView platxtlist;
        public TextView posetxtlist;
        public TextView formatxtlist;
        public TextView avatxtlist;
        public TextView vectxtlist;

        public jHolder(View itemViewer){
            super(itemViewer);
            titxtlist=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titltxt);
            platxtlist=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.platxtlist);
            posetxtlist=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.posetxtlist);
            formatxtlist=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.formatxtlist);
            avatxtlist=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.avatxtlist);
            vectxtlist=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.vectxtlist);

        }
    }
}
```

The XML file for every Recycler object:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#505050"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titxtlist"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/platxtlist"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/posetxtlist"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/formatxtlist"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/avatxtlist"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vectxtlist"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The XML file for the RecyclerView Activity:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#919191"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Lista">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btntitlsrc"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Todos" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spnplataformal"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#B6A9A9" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spnposesionl"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#B6A9A9" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spnformatol"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#B6A9A9" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spnavancel"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#B6A9A9" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spnvecesl"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#B6A9A9" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!--
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstvwlistgrand"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
          -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclergrande"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

The Logcat says this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.prueba.Adaptagrande.onBindViewHolder(Adaptagrande.java:37)
        at com.example.prueba.Adaptagrande.onBindViewHolder(Adaptagrande.java:15)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6781)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6823)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5752)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6019)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:753)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2792)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2319)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
2019-05-31 18:04:00.987 6377-6377/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

But i don't see where is the null reference or the error receiving or transforming the data

Comment: Please edit the post and add the complete output of logcat as currently there's no way to see where the NullPointerException is occurring. Currently your RecyclerView and Adapter seem to be fine. Update your question and add more of your logcat error

Comment: okay, now i added all the output from the logcat but still can`t see my error

Comment: You logcat says that your holder textviews are null.

Comment: @ivan, that's true but I don't see that he didn't initialize textview by mistake. The code seems to be correct from what I see. I might be wrong due to variable names that are used. If possible can you tell me what's exactly on line no 37 in your adapter?

Comment: @VedprakashWagh The 1st textview is null because the id that he is using is nonexistent in the view that he is looking it for.

Comment: Dang it. SO hard to notice with those variable names that are used. I saw that code couple of times but couldn't notice the difference. @ivan

Comment: @VedprakashWagh haha yeah its easy to miss a typo in those variables what caught my attention was the variable name being different from the actual id

Comment: @VedprakashWagh  so i misspelled the names or did i change the reference for a diferent xml element?

Comment: You misspelled the R.id.titltxt. In your layout file it's titxtlist, so it should be R.id.titxtlist

Comment: Okay, i found it, it was at the end of my adapter, thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it is just a typo .. The id for titxtlist is wrong. You are finding textview in your viewholder by using id as

```
titxtlist=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titltxt);
```

but in your layout file it is

```
android:id="@+id/titxtlist"
```

**The id is not same in your viewholder**